# Differentiate $ f(x) = \frac 2x $ from first principles

Tags: calculus

I have $$ f(x) = \frac 2x $$

and I have to differentiate from first principle. I have gotten to putting $ f(x) $ and $f(x+h) $ into the equation and I got $$ f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \left\{ \frac{ -2}{x^2 + x} \right\}$$
However the correct answer doesn't have the $ + x $ on the bottom and i cannot work out how to get rid of it.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how you got from $f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ to the expression you show in your question.

Comment: for $ f(x+h) $ i got $ \frac 2(x+h) $ which after putting into the equation i ended up with $ \frac{ \frac 2(x+h) - \frac 2x }{h} $ after i made the denominators the same and done the subtraction i ended up with $ \frac { \frac{ -2h }{ x(x+h) } }{h} $ after removing the h i got the expression in the question

Comment: That looks fine.  And then you can cancel the topmost $h$ with the bottommost $h$ (the $h$ in the middle level stays in the expression).

Comment: Ah that would be the catch, i had expanded the middle bracket and took the h out with it so when i had $$ \lim_{h\to 0} $$ it did not take away the x.

Comment: Good.  Glad you got that worked out!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should end up with

$$
\begin{align}
f'(x) &=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\frac2{x+h}-\frac2x}h\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2x-2(x+h)}{hx(x+h)}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{-2h}{hx(x+h)}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-2}{x(x+h)}
\end{align}
$$

rather than what you have. Can you solve from here?

Answer (score 5):

$$f'(x):=\lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right] \equiv \lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{\frac{2}{x+h}-\frac{2}{x}}{h}\right] $$

$$\equiv\lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{\frac{2}{x+h}-\frac{2}{x}}{h} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{x(x+h)}{x(x+h)}}_{1}\right]$$
$$\equiv\lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{2x-2(x+h)}{hx(x+h)}\right]$$

$$\require{cancel} \equiv\lim_{h \to 0}\left[\frac{-2\cancel{h}}{\cancel{h}x(x+h)}\right]$$

$$\equiv \lim_{h \to 0}\left[\frac{-2}{x^2+\cancelto{0}{xh}}\right]$$

$$ \equiv\Large \boxed{-\frac{2}{x^2}}$$